# QGIS Data Plotly - Overlapping data format not preserved when selecting different features

Tags: qgis, plotly

I'm using Data Plotly to create scatter charts with two data sets plotted on each chart:

1. Observed values over time, and
2. Modeled values over time.

I have hundreds of locations that have both observed and modeled results with data in the following format:

```
Name, X, Y, time, observed_value, modelled_value
```

...and using Data Plotly with the 'use only selected features' option should allow me to look at the modeled results compared to the observed data at any location that I select, if I understand correctly.

However, the problem I am having is that after I create an overlapping scatter chart with both variables:
[image: chart with two variables]

...and I drag a box around a different data location to change the data on the chart, the first variable always gets lost (even if I try to view the data at the original location again), in this case the computed line goes away (even though this location definitely has computed data that can be plotted):
[image: lost variable]

Is this the intended behavior? If not, is there any way to prevent the overlapping data charts from losing the overlapping data every time you select a new location to view?